# rails3: JQuery not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

New to both JQuery and Rails, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm following the RailsCast tutorial on [dynamic select menus](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=comments) but when I try loading the form, the dynamic selection doesn't work and I get an error in firebug stating JQuery is not loaded. I checked assets/application.js and the function seems to be loaded correctly. I also have javascript_include_tag included in my layout file before any other content gets yielded. I tried pre-compiling my assets but that didn't seem to do anything.

The weird thing is I have another JQuery function defined for another controller and that function is working perfectly fine. I'm completely baffled by what's going on here.

**Update - adding code snippets.**

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
    <head>
      <title> <%= default_title(yield(:title)) %> </title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    ...
    <div class="container">
      ...
      <%= yield %>  
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
```

hostprofiles.js.coffee

```
JQuery ->
    cities = $('#hostprofile_city_id').html()
    console.log(cities)
    $('#hostprofile_country_id').change ->
        country = $('#hostprofile_country_id :selected').text()
        escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')   
        options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[lable=#{escaped_country}]").html()
        console.log(options)
        if options
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').html(options)
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').empty()
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').parent().hide()
```

generated jquery function is application.js

```
(function() {   
      JQuery(function() {
        var cities;
        cities = $('#hostprofile_city_id').html();
        console.log(cities);
        return $('#hostprofile_country_id').change(function() {
          var country, escaped_country, options;
          country = $('#hostprofile_country_id :selected').text();
          escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
          options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[lable=" + escaped_country + "]").html();
          console.log(options);
          if (options) {
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').html(options);
            return $('#hostprofile_city_id').parent().show();
          } else {
            $('#hostprofile_city_id').empty();
            return $('#hostprofile_city_id').parent().hide();
          }
        });
      });

    }).call(this);
```

Comment: we need to see your code to help you out, otherwise we would be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. Really stupid mistake on my part, I capitalized the 'j' in jQuery in my function. Apologies for such a stupid mistake.

Comment: don't forget to accept your answer when you're able to do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out that jQuery is loaded in the page source (F12 if you use FF or Chrome). Also check if there are JavaScript errors before the code you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

into Gemfile check this

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and into app/assets/javascript/application.js check if you have this text

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

the line //= require jquery load jQuery into Rails 3

Comment: Yes, I have all of that. As i mentioned before, I have another JQuery function that works perfectly fine. Same app, just a different controller.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might stumble upon this, I had the same problem but in my case it was caused by having - for some surprising reason - required jquery twice.

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery
...
```

Taking out the extra one did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After many searches.  (24 hours worth!)  Here is what I found out.

Given this this Rails setup.

```
$ gem list --local | egrep "jquery|rails"
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
jquery-rails (3.0.1)
rails (3.2.13)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
```

This is application.js manifest snippet.  This what Rails 3.2.13 gives you as default.
No problem.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

rails generate controller session index new create edit destroy

The form looks like this.

You will need to add div id around the form

(Don't forget the :remote => true)

```
<div id="login_form">
  <% if flash[:alert] %>
    <p id="notice" ><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_tag  :remote => true  do %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Please Log In</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="name" >Name:</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password" >Password:</label>
        <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
      </div>
      <div id="login_submit_button">
        <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

I created a javascript file with the following.

**jQuery.noConflict();**  is the key!

```
//./app/assets/javascripts/my_session.js

// These requires tell manifest to load these first from application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs


// $.fn  is  alias for   Jquery.prototype
//
// You can define plugins like this.
jQuery.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("hello");
}

// Or, you may wish to use the $.fn
jQuery.noConflict();            // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
(function($) {
    $.fn.world = function() {
        alert("world");
    };                        // watch your semicolons!!

    $.fn.clearForm = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (tag == 'form')
                return $(':input', this).clearForm();
            if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
                this.value = '';
            else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
                this.checked = false;
            else if (tag == 'select')
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    if ($("#login_form").length) {  // If exists, then reset
        //$("#login_form form")[0].reset();
        $().hello();
        $().world();
        $("#login_form form").clearForm();
    }
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.


// OR, you can just use JQuery in place of $     (The plugins hello and world still need the above magic though!)

//jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//    if (jQuery("#login_form").length) {  // If exists, then reset
//        jQuery("#login_form form")[0].reset();
//        jQuery().hello();
//        jQuery().world();
//    }
//});
```